# Sqlite3 maximum primary key value

Tags: php, sqlite

I have table with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and I cannot insert value greater then 2147483647 as a key. Is it possible to increase this value somehow?

UPDATE:
Ok, I have php script:

```
<?php

$sqlite_db = new SQLite3('test');
$sqlite_db->exec('CREATE TABLE test (n UNSIGNED INTEGER)');

$ns = array(1111111111,2222222222,3333333333,4444444444,5555555555,6666666666,7777777777);

foreach ($ns as $n)
{
    $statement = $sqlite_db->prepare('INSERT INTO test (n) VALUES (:n)');
    $statement->bindValue(':n', $n, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $statement->execute();
}

$sqlite_db->close();
?>
```

and what I get in test database is that:

```
root@localhost:~# sqlite3 test 
SQLite version 3.7.3
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from test;
1111111111
-2072745074
-961633963
149477148
1260588259
-1923267926
-812156815
```

So my question is: how to insert large values into sqlite database from php?

UPDATE2:

I have changed foreach body to:

```
$sqlite_db->exec("INSERT INTO test (n) VALUES ({$n})");
```

and it works ok now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen that behavior with SQLite3. Edit your question, and paste the output of `.schema your-table-name`.  Also, make sure the problem isn't in your application code.

[Declaring a column as integer in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) works differently than declaring a column as integer in a true SQL dbms. In SQLite3, any column declared `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` ought to accept any 64-bit, signed integer. 64-bit integers max go to 1.84467441 × 10<sup>19</sup>. (Your column should accept negative integers, too.)

> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
>   bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

```
sqlite> create table t ( n integer primary key, s varchar(35));
sqlite> insert into t (s) values ('a');
sqlite> insert into t (s) values ('a');
sqlite> insert into t (s) values ('a');
sqlite> select * from t;
1|a
2|a
3|a
```

So, it automatically increments . . .

```
sqlite> insert into t values (2147483647, 'a');
sqlite> select * from t;
1|a
2|a
3|a
2147483647|a
```

And it accepts the maximum value of a 32-bit signed integer.

```
sqlite> insert into t (s) values ('a');
sqlite> insert into t (s) values ('a');
sqlite> insert into t (s) values ('a');
sqlite> select * from t;
1|a
2|a
3|a
2147483647|a
2147483648|a
2147483649|a
2147483650|a
```

And it increments *past* the maximum value of a 32-bit signed integer.

```
sqlite> insert into t values (8589934592, 'a');
sqlite> select * from t;
1|a
2|a
3|a
2147483647|a
2147483648|a
2147483649|a
2147483650|a
8589934592|a
```

It accepts values in the range of 2<sup>33</sup>.

```
sqlite> insert into t (s) values ('a');
sqlite> select * from t;
1|a
2|a
3|a
2147483647|a
2147483648|a
2147483649|a
2147483650|a
8589934592|a
8589934593|a
```

And it continues to automatically increment.

Answer (score 1):

The 2147483647 is the max value of integer, this mean that greater number will not fit into it because will not have space.

The integer are represented usually using  4 bytes (32 bits), where last bit is the sing.

```
    31                  15                0
    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 = 0 

    0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 = +2147483647  

    1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 = -2147483647
```

From the documentation:

> One exception to the typelessness of SQLite is a column whose type is
>   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. (And you must use "INTEGER" not "INT". A column
>   of type INT PRIMARY KEY is typeless just like any other.) INTEGER
>   PRIMARY KEY columns must contain a 32-bit signed integer. Any attempt
>   to insert non-integer data will result in an error.
>
> INTEGER PRIMARY KEY columns can be used to implement the equivalent of
>   AUTOINCREMENT. If you try to insert a NULL into an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
>   column, the column will actually be filled with an integer that is one
>   greater than the largest key already in the table. Or if the largest
>   key is 2147483647, then the column will be filled with a random
>   integer. Either way, the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column will be assigned a
>   unique integer. You can retrieve this integer using the
>   sqlite_last_insert_rowid() API function or using the
>   last_insert_rowid() SQL function in a subsequent SELECT statement.

[source](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html)

From Version 3 of SQLite supports the integers on 2,4,6 or 8 bytes and the row id is on 64 bit.

So if you have version less then 3 the answer is, no you can not do anything about that.

Comment: Thumb up for point out the change in Sqlite3. The reference is [here](http://www.sqlite.org/version3.html)